# EndOfFile error

Tags: programming, streams

I have a LARGE file (14.6 GB) that I want to separate into several smaller files. Because of its size, using Import/Export is not feasible, I think the most reasonable way of handling this would be using the file as a stream

```
stream = OpenRead[filepath]
```

then with

```
Read[stream, String]
```

I can select what I want, and hold the strings in a temporary list until that is large enough to warrant being exported and cleared.

The problem is that when Read[stream,String] encounters ASCII character 0x1A, *Mathematica* interprets it as an EndOfFile, even when it's not. Any suggestions to get around this?

Edit: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sm51m2s19wtnoqa/allascii.txt is a text file with all ASCII characters, if read in as a stream, this error should be reproduced

Comment: Looks like you need [BinaryReadList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryReadList.html).

Comment: 1A is really a kind of EOF: see [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character).

Comment: Is this a binary file or a plain text file?  Plain text files shouldn't have that character ... if it's a binary file, use `BinaryFormat -> True` in `OpenRead`.

Answer (score 3):

Long, long ago, but right here and not in a galaxy far, far away, there was an operating system called MS-DOS that used the character 0x1A as an end-of-file flag. Windows inherited this in its early days. I would have thought that it was eliminated by now, but perhaps not. *Mathematica* is old enough that it has a system constant `$IgnoreEOF`. It should be `True` by default, but it isn't, so

```
$IgnoreEOF = True
```

should fix things.